# BlackBerry issue with Textfields in OS6

Tags: blackberry, java-me, j2mepolish

I'm developing a BlackBerry app and using J2ME Polish to do the styling. So, I'm using TextFields with styling from Polish to get user input.

The TextFields work fine in OS versions other than 6. But when testing on devices running OS 6, the Textfields break.

Basically in other versions of the OS, when focus is on a TextField then the left and right buttons move the cursor around in the TextField and up and down moves focus to the next/previous item. However, in OS6 up and down instead navigate to the beginning and end of the TextField respectively and focus gets stuck so I'm not able to move focus to the next item.

As a workaround I tried to capture the down button using handleKeyReleased, but when focus is on the TextField the down button isn't even being captured.

Does anyone know of any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by explicitly using the BlackBerry JDE version 6 to build the app.